# Move substrings to another line

Tags: bash

I have the following code:

```
echo "Getting valid types"
while read line;
do
    answer=$(curl -s http://localhost:8890/sparql --data-urlencode "query=
            SELECT  DISTINCT ?type WHERE {
<$line> a ?type.
FILTER regex(?type,'dbpedia.org','i')
}" --data-urlencode "format=text/csv")
    type=$(echo $answer | cut -d ' ' -f 2- | sed s/\"//g | grep -v type)
    echo $type >> valid_instance_types
done < "valid_urls"
echo "Done"
```

It returns a file like this (with empty lines as you can see):

```
http://dbpedia.org/ontology/MusicalWork http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Song http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Work

http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Organisation http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Agent http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Band http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Group

http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Organisation http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Agent http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Band http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Group
```

I want to have each url in a line and omit blank lines but I don't know how to do it:

```
http://dbpedia.org/ontology/MusicalWork
http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Song
http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Work
http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Organisation
http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Agent
http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Band
http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Group
http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Organisation
http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Agent
http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Band
http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Group
```

Hope you can help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `awk -v OFS='\n' -v RS=' ' '/http/{$1=$1}1' valid_instance_types`

Comment: @Jetchisel, you could also use `awk ... 'NF {$1=$1} 1' file` to ignore blank lines.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Jetchisel's awk command, grep works to find all sequences of non-blank characters:

```sh
grep -E -o '[^[:blank:]]+' file
```